# tapestry grid default sorting

Tags: sorting, grid, tapestry

I would like to specify a default sorting column of a tapestry grid.

I understand that I could sort the records in my getter on the server side, however this seems like unnecessary effort, since grid is perfectly capable of sorting on it's own.

So my grid definition looks like:

```xml
<t:grid source="queues" inPlace="true"> </t:grid>
```

The getQueues returns collection of objects like:

```java
public class Queue {
    public String getName();
    public float getOccupancy();
}
```

I would like to make the grid sorted by 'occupancy' attribute in descendent order by default.

From the Tapestry documentation I see, that Grid has attribute **sortModel** which seems like the right option. However I can't find good explanation of what are the right values to set it to.

Answer (score 6):

You could probably write a mixin to set the initial sort

```
@MixinAfter
public class DefaultSort {
    public enum Order { ASCENDING, DESCENDING };

    @Parameter(required=true, defaultPrefix="literal")
    private String sort;

    @Parameter(defaultPrefix="literal", value="literal:ascending")
    private Order order;

    @InjectContainer
    private Grid grid;

    @SetupRender
    void setupRender() {
        GridSortModel sortModel = grid.getSortModel();
        if (sortModel.getSortConstraints().isEmpty()) {
            sortModel.updateSort(sort);
            if (order == Order.DESCENDING) {
               // updateSort a second time for DESCENDING
               sortModel.updateSort(sort);
            }
        }
    }
}

<t:grid source="queues" inPlace="true" t:mixins="defaultsort" sort="occupancy" />
```

Comment: Interesting. Your solution works and taught me more about tapestry. However it only allows me to set the sorting in ascending order. I am having trouble to switch the sorting order programmatically.

Comment: Just call GridSortModel.updateSort() again for the same property. You can interrogate the SortConstraints to test for [ColumnSort.ASCENDING](http://tapestry.apache.org/5.3/apidocs/org/apache/tapestry5/grid/ColumnSort.html#ASCENDING) etc

Comment: i can see the sort icon is updated, but the data is not sorted.